# Content Query Web Part within custom list form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

I am currently inserting a Content Query Web Part inside a custom **Edit form** for a **list**. The idea is to display a link to a file in a Document Library. I got it all to work except the **filter** in the content query.

The Document Library has an added single text column for Client Name. The list has a **Lookup Column** to get the Client Name from the Document Library.

I am setting the filter in the Content Query as follows:

> Show Items When: ClientName is equal to [PageFieldValue: Client]

**ClientName** is the column in the Document Library. **Client** is the lookup column in the list for which the custom form is being created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `PageFieldValue` token can only be used inside a Publishing page, not in a list form.
I'd rather go with a Script Web part. It would link to the [SPService](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) script (for instance) that you could use to get the current value for the list item, and request the document URL in the doc lib. Your script would then format a `<a>` tag.

Comment: I am basically trying to replicate work done previously on our site. This is the way the previous developer had it. Although I can see everything the previous developer did I cannot get it to work the same. I'll try the script web part later today.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to scrap the idea and take a whole different approach.

Thanks anyways